# Problem: Shutting down pc resets powerline fonts so they don't appear in VS Code (but they do in Ubuntu terminal)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, fonts, oh-my-zsh, powerline

I managed to get the Powerline fonts working on my Windows 10 pc to use in WSL, particularly in the VS Code terminal window so I can use the Agnoster oh-my-zsh terminal theme. I set it all up and everything works - cool.

**BUT** when I shutdown my pc and restart it, the font no longer works in VS Code.
However, it does still work in the ubuntu window.  See ↓

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UUT2.png -- Sorry, I don't have enough rep to post images :(

---

I noticed it is not installed in the settings > font window

But it is installed in the control panel fonts window.

---

**Current workaround**

I can get the font to work again if I reinstall the font, at which point Windows will prompt me that *The font is already installed, do I want to reinstall?*. Click yes.

At which point the font will appear in the fonts settings (Add fonts) window.

---

What is going wrong with the font installation? Reinstalling the font after every boot seems tedious... I suppose I can get a script to automate that on startup but I really want to get to the root cause.

---

**EDIT**

So I just found the fix - had to right click on the .ttf file and ️*Install for all users*.

I don't know why installing it as the local user didn't work but hey ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since you seem to have found the answer yourself, I'd recommend [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so someone else who has the same problem can more easily find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question...

Have to right click on the .ttf file and `️Install for all users.`

It seems that if the font is not listed in the Settings > Personalization > Fonts window, VS Code will not find it. Installing for all users makes the font persist there after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Powerline Fonts with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-powerline
```

And starting VS Code from your WSL prompt with command  `code .`